# How to connect aws postgres db over the ssh using python

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel

I have a Postgres db over the AWS and currently we connect that using postico client by providing below information-
DB Host
DB Port
DB Username
DB Password
DB Name
SSH Host (it is domain)
SSH Port
SSH Private Key
During this time I used to my organisation VPN. But Now I have to connect the same with python code and I believe when I can connect the with postico I should be through code as well. I have used below code but unable to connect to db and fetch records so anyone can give idea or sample code?-

```
def __init__(self, pgres_host, pgres_port, db, ssh, ssh_user, ssh_host, ssh_pkey):
        # SSH Tunnel Variables
        self.pgres_host = pgres_host
        self.pgres_port = pgres_port
        
        if ssh == True:
            self.server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
                (ssh_host, 22),
                ssh_username=ssh_user,
                ssh_private_key=ssh_pkey,
                remote_bind_address=(pgres_host, pgres_port),
            )
            server = self.server
            server.start() #start ssh server
            self.local_port = server.local_bind_port
            
            print(f'Server connected via SSH || Local Port: {self.local_port}...')
        elif ssh == False:
            pass

def query(self, db, query, psql_user, psql_pass):
        engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{psql_user}:{psql_pass}@{self.pgres_host}:{self.local_port}/{db}')
        print (f'Database [{db}] session created...')
        print(f'host [{self.pgres_host}]')
        self.query_df = pd.read_sql(query,engine)
        print ('<> Query Sucessful <>')
        engine.dispose()
        return self.query_df

pgres = Postgresql_connect(pgres_host=p_host, pgres_port=p_port, db=db, ssh=ssh, ssh_user=ssh_user, ssh_host=ssh_host, ssh_pkey=ssh_pkey)
print(ssh_pkey)
query_df = pgres.query(db=db, query='Select * from table', psql_user=user, psql_pass=password)
print(query_df)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @jjanes Timeout error

Answer (score 0):

connect just as you would locally after creating an ssh tunnel

https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/